# How can I add an header to all endpoints in Yesod appication?

Tags: security, haskell, http-headers, yesod

I have an [yesod](/questions/tagged/yesod) application.
I need to add an specific header to all responses.
It's clear how to do it with an specific endpoint using [addHeader](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.14/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:addHeader).

Let's say this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

**Question:**

How can I configure an header once for all endpoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alter the [**`yesodMiddleware :: Yesod site => HandlerFor site res -> HandlerFor site res`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.14/docs/Yesod-Core.html#v:yesodMiddleware) field in the `instance Yesod App` of your `App`. For example with:

```
instance Yesod App where
    -- ...
    yesodMiddleware handler = do
        addHeader "X-Frame-Options" "sameorigin"
        defaultYesodMiddleware handler
```

The `yesodMiddleware` is thus functionality that is "wrapped around" the target handler. You can do tasks before you query the handler, and after the handler (for example to postprocess the result).